# How to maintain the navigation with a segue "present modally"?

Tags: swift, xcode

[image]
I have :  navigation controller -> tableViewController -> tab bar Controller -> ViewController1 / ViewController2 / ViewController3

I click on a cell on the TableViewController and I open the TabBar. All is OK

But, I wanted to have more details from the datas in the TableViewController so I decided to make a popup with the content of the cell. I found this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=S5i8n_bqblE => GREAT ! It's about the use of segue "present modally" with a viewcontroller containing the popup. I made a link from the popup to the tabBarController and I lose the Navigation Bar

[image]

I tried to play with navigationBar but nothing is working. I changed the type of segue but I don't obtain what I want.

I think the problem come from the type of segue. It's OK if I use it like a go/back in viewController. Do you have any solution about using this sort of popup or do I have to use another way ?

Thanks

Comment: Wrap modally presented controller into new navigation controller

Comment: Hello @SergeyGamayunov OK, thanks. I made what you said. It's running ! But I lose the effect of the tableview visible behind the popup. Is there a way to make it possible ? It's the goal of using this type of popup I think... Thanks

Comment: Can you provide screenshots before and after? I'm not sure I understood you correctly

Comment: @SergeyGamayunov Hello Sergey, do you have any solution ? Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Ok, let's take a look.

1. Navigation Bar is a view which is provided by Navigation Controller. Sometimes we are confused with navigation bars and navigation items. Navigation bar is the only one and it belongs to navigation controller, navigation item belongs to individual view controller from navigation stack. So, first step is simple: if you want navigation bar, wrap your modally presented controller into navigation stack.
2. Yes, you will face other problem, the blurred view of previous controller will become a black area. Why? there is special object called Presentation Controller (`UIPresentationController`) which is responsible for how controller will be presented. And it hides view of previous controller by default (in sake of performance, I think).
3. Ok, let's move. We can create custom presentation controller and tell it not to hide view of previous controller. Like this:

```
class CustomPresentationController: UIPresentationController {
    override var shouldRemovePresentersView: Bool {
        return false
    }
}
```

4. Next step. In controller we want present modally we have to specify to things: we want to use custom presentation controller and we also want to adjust delegate object for transitioning (where we can specify custom presentation controller). The trick is that you have to do it inside initialiser, because `viewDidLoad` is too late: controller had been already initialised:

```
class PopupViewController: UIViewController {
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)

        modalPresentationStyle = .custom
        transitioningDelegate = self
    }
}
```

5. Final step. When `PopupViewController` became delegate for its own transitioning, it means this controller is responsible for all of them. In our particular case popup controller provides custom version of presentation controller. Like this:

```
extension PopupViewController: UIViewControllerTransitioningDelegate {
    func presentationController(forPresented presented: UIViewController, presenting: UIViewController?, source: UIViewController) -> UIPresentationController? {
        return CustomPresentationController(presentedViewController: presented, presenting: presenting)
    }
}
```

That's all. Now you should see view of previous controller.

Comment: Hello @SergeyGamayunov, I have just tried your way but no change. The navigation bar is always absent